# Short story where spacers meet "death by silk" while on shore leave

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I really should be able to find this but it eludes me.

It's a short story I read in an anthology about a group of spacers getting shore leave on a planet.

One of the men chose to forgo leaving the ship and when his friend asked him about it he says he had been on the planet before and warns his friend that the planet's inhabitants can kill with kindness: I seem to remember the phrase "death by silk".

The designated location for shore leave is in a slum-like area on the planet where the non-productive members of society go to live fast, die young and leave a beautiful corpse. All forms of recreational drugs are legal and freely provided.

Unfortunately for the spacers there are drugs in everything, even the food and they are highly addictive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are seeking the short story "Trial by Silk" by Christopher Anvil.  You can find it in the collection Interstellar Patrol II edited by Eric Flint.

[Interstellar Patrol II](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?68662)

[Trial By Silk](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66639)

[Wiki Christopher Anvil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Anvil)

Comment: aye thats it, thanks.